# Excel formula with if function

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me with this,
I would like to classify each amount in column E below or equal to the amoun in column B.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `F2` and copy it down to `F21`

```
=IF(E2<=$B$14,IF(E2<=$B$13,IF(E2<=$B$12,IF(E2<=$B$11,IF(E2<=$B$10,IF(E2<=$B$9,IF(E2<=$B$8,IF(E2<=$B$7,IF(E2<=$B$6,IF(E2<=$B$5,IF(E2<=$B$4,IF(E2<=$B$3,IF(E2<=$B$2,$A$2,$A$3),$A$4),$A$5),$A$6),$A$7),$A$8),$A$9),$A$10),$A$11),$A$12),$A$13),$A$14),$A$14)
```